# Редирект на другую страницу после успешного заказа товара в магазине

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, как в WP, а именно, в WooCommerce, реализовать редирект после успешного заказа на сайте. То есть, если оплата прошла успешно, то мы перенаправляем на другую страницу, если же произошла ошибка в оформлении заказа или заказ не был обработан, то ничего не делать.

Comment: Так редирект и происходит. По умолчанию - на /order-received/

Comment: Ну я подключил платежный шлюз "nmi" и через него произвожу оплату, но если ввел неправильную инфу то оно выводит в карте товара ошибку что как бы меня устраивает. А мне нужно чтоб условно выводило  "оплата совершенна успешно" или не выводило и дальше переходило на другую страничку с дополнительной формой контактов, не могу сделать пока. К чему привязаться и за что дергать пока тоже не пойму.

Comment: Ну а что сразу-то не написали? Платёжный шлюз - другая история. Это отдельный плагин. Обычно в установках платёжного шлюза (у них на сайте, в аккаунте) задаются url возврата.

Comment: Нет там урл возврата там есть только вывод сообщения условно говоря "ваш платеж прошел успешно" и "ваш платеж не прошел успешно потому что...."! =)

Comment: Платеж где выполняется - на их сервере?

Comment: @KAGG Design Да.

Comment: @KAGG Design Если платеж совершенн удачно то приходит сообщение "Transaction was approved" если неудачно то один из вариантов "Transaction was rejected by gateway" , думал уже выбрать все что между тегов, тупо текст и сравнить с тем текстом который приходит когда успешно прошел платеж. Клиент хочет чтоб анкета дополнительная вылазила на отдельной странице после удачной оплаты, вот пока смотрю в сторону джс и ищю в инете как это сделать ибо познания в джс и джквери пока хватает как подключить готовый скрипт или подпилить под себя. Сижу целый день уже ломаю голову.

Comment: Плагин доступен для скачивания?

Comment: @KAGG Design да, https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-nmi-three-step/

Comment: Я полез в код - и удивился. У вас же в настройках плагина nmi есть Return URL, на странице /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout&section=nmi_three_step ну и поставьте там то, что хочется. Судя по коду, туда переход производится только при успешном платеже.

Comment: @KAGG Design да действительно есть) +копнув код нашел где добавить свой вывод)

Answer (score 1):

Редирект можно сделать добавив этот код в function.php вашей темы.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'URL куда будем делать редирект' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Теперь можно просто создать страницу "спасибо за заказ" и оформить как угодно.

Comment: а как сделать редирект если ошибка?ошибки могут быть разные и скрипт должен понять что и куда надо в этом случае перенаправить

Comment: добавляйте условия в данный скрипт